# How to determine the number of times a word appears in an input

Tags: python, arrays

I have a situation, the user can input a list of words separated by "," (For example: iceCream, Dog, Cat). At the end, I have to say how many words the user inputted, how many letters he entered and the number of times the user inputs the word "yeet" ( with two or more "e"). Example, if the user inputs: dog,cat,yeet,yeeet,yeete. The program will return "you used 5 words, 20 letters and 2 yeets". This is what I have so far:

```
array = input("Enter your words seperated by a comma,(for e.g rohit,bohit,sohit,lohit)").lower()
words = len(array.split(","))
letters = len(array)
yeets = 0
for i in array:
  if array.startswith("y") and array.endswith("t"):
    yeets += 1
print("You entered", words, "words with", letters, "letters and it has", yeets, "yeets!")
```

Comment: you should be checking `i`, not `array`, in the loop. Also, it will match `yoot`, `yit`, etc.

Comment: Can you update the post to include any issues or errors you're running into? What specifically are you asking about here?

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, use a regex that it starts with y, ends with t, and has 2 or more e's in the middle

```
import re
for word in array:
  if re.match("^yee+t$", word):
    yeets += 1
```

EDIT: uses regex instead of perfect match

Comment: He said **two or more e**

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the words in the string, not the characters in the string.

You can use a regular expression to match `y` followed by at least 2 `e` followed by `t`.

```
import re

wordlist = array.split(',')
yeets = len([word for word in wordlist if re.match(r'^ye{2,}t$', word)])
```

Comment: It says invalid syntax

Comment: Fixed the syntax.